# Python 3.x Threading: "RuntimeError: release unlocked lock" in Sleeping Barber problem

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, runtime-error, deadlock

**My problem:**

I've begun learning about Threading in Python, so I decided trying to implement the "Sleeping Barber Problem" knowing only the logic behind it. However, I've encountered an issue: if using a higher number of threads and/or a `time.sleep()` time that is too low (I'm using it for debugging purposes), I will eventually end up with a `RuntimeError: release unlocked lock`, since it is trying to release my "customer_ready" lock (`cliente_pronto` in my code) when it has already been released, something that from what I understand (and I may probably be wrong), shouldn't happen.

What could I be missing here?

**My code:**

```
import threading

barbeiro_pronto = threading.Lock()
wr_acessivel = threading.Lock() 
cliente_pronto = threading.Lock()
num_assentos_livres = 10
clientes = []

barbeiro_pronto.acquire() 
cliente_pronto.acquire()

def barbeiro():
  global num_assentos_livres
  global barbeiro_pronto
  global wr_acessivel
  global cliente_pronto

  while (True):
    cliente_pronto.acquire()
    wr_acessivel.acquire()
    num_assentos_livres+=1
    barbeiro_pronto.release()
    wr_acessivel.release()

def cliente():
  global num_assentos_livres
  global barbeiro_pronto
  global wr_acessivel
  global cliente_pronto

  while (True):
    wr_acessivel.acquire()
    if num_assentos_livres > 0:
      num_assentos_livres-=1
      cliente_pronto.release()
      wr_acessivel.release()
      barbeiro_pronto.acquire()
      return
    else:
      wr_acessivel.release()

thread_barbeiro = threading.Thread(target=barbeiro)
thread_barbeiro.start()

for i in range(15):
  thread_cliente = threading.Thread(target=cliente)
  thread_cliente.start()
  clientes.append(thread_cliente)

while (True):
  pass
```

**What I've tried:**

I tried putting an `if cliente_pronto.locked():` before releasing such lock. However this results in the problem that all my threads running the `cliente` function either return not having run all their code, or enter a deadlock along with my `barbeiro` function (Couldn't point which of the two cases: it seems to be just on my debugging alone).

Comment: As an aside, you only need `global` when assigning to a variable. `cliente_pronto`does not need to be global for `cliente_pronto.acquire()` to work.